# Moving pages top of the SharePoint search results

Tags: enterprise-search, sharepoint-search

We are using SharePoint 2010 search and we would like to see aspx pages on top of the search result. Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, by using a custom ranking model.

To quote [this blog post](http://www.sharepoint13blog.com/sharepoint-2010-search-ranking-model-and-results-relevance/):

> For example, if you want to promote result items of a specific type
>   such as PDF documents, you can give search items with the file
>   extension .pdf additional points.

There are a number of links to other resources about the subject at the end of that post.

Here is the MSDN page for the [ranking model schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558793%28v=office.14%29.aspx), and here is [a question on the MSDN SharePoint forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/86b460a2-57b1-491d-9e1c-44b00807b7a1/related-articles-for-relevancy-model-for-sharepoint-server-2010?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) that has several useful answers about how to use and work with ranking models.

I've never tried to work with custom ranking models myself, so I can't provide any personal insight or answers from experience, but it certainly seems as though it can be done.